# SSIS SQL Task Unable to assign Parameter Value when using IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm using VS 2012 and SQL Server / SSIS.

I originally had a SQL task to check for duplicate values in a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS DupNI
FROM dbo.mytable
WHERE XMLFileID = ?
GROUP BY XMLFileID, NINumber
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1);
```

The `?` is because I am inserting a parameter value, and the result of the query is being assigned to a variable. It works fine if there is a duplicate.

When there are no duplicates, I get this message:

> Single Row result set is specified, but no rows were returned

So, to get round this I now use an IF EXISTS, like the below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) AS DupNI
           FROM dbo.mytable
           WHERE XMLFileID = ?
           GROUP BY XMLFileID, NINumber
           HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS DupNI
    FROM dbo.mytable
    WHERE XMLFileID = ?
    GROUP BY XMLFileID, NINumber
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
ELSE
    SELECT 0 AS DupNI;
```

However, now I get the error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

It appears because I am wrapping the statement in the IF EXISTS, I can no longer inject the parameter values via the ?

Why is this? How do I get around this issue?

Comment: You have 2 `?` in your query, so SSIS sees 2 parameters. Either assign the value of the parameter to a variable, and use that, or pass the parameter twice. But why have the `HAVING` clause in the first query? Why not check the value outside of the query (in SSIS) and do what you need to do if the value is greater than 1?

Comment: If you put that as an answer, @Larnu I'd upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query will return multiple rows if there are duplicates, one for each duplicate `(XMLFileID, NINumber)` pair. If you only want to return a value which indicates whether there are any duplicates in the table, you could use your `EXISTS` clause as an expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS DupNI
  FROM dbo.mytable
  WHERE XMLFileID = ?
  GROUP BY XMLFileID, NINumber
  HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Duplicates Exist]
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=78ef019921b110cb90219ff511f71947)